# Geth Archiver node configuration

Tags: go-ethereum, archive-node

I am interested in running a Geth archiver node and I noticed in the offical documentation that in order to do that states:

> Archive nodes are created by configuring Geth's garbage collection so that old data is never deleted: `geth --syncmode full --gcmode archive`

I also noticed that there is a configuration parameter called `NoPruning = false`.

What is the difference between these two configurations. Can I create an archive node by enabling `NoPruning` and not set `--gcmode` to archive?

Should I use both to run an archiver node successfully?

Answer (score 0):

--gcmode archive will never delete any data, while NoPruning=false will only keep the data that is necessary for the current state of the blockchain.

If you want to create an archive node, you should use both --gcmode archive and NoPruning=false.

This will ensure that all of the data is preserved, and that you can access the entire history of the blockchain.